# Taggle inside Featherlight Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a Form with Tags that uses [Featherlight](https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/) and [Taggle](https://sean.is/poppin/tags).

When you type a tag and separate with commas, they turn into styled boxes.

But the tags don't style when in the Featherlight form.

**Demo**

https://jsfiddle.net/wpeLxo1e/1/

**HTML**

```
<body>

  <br />

  <!-- Featherlight Button -->
  <p><a href="#" data-featherlight="#myform">Open Featherlight</a></p>

  <!-- Featherlight Form -->
  <div class="container">
    <form id="myform" class="form">
      <!-- Tags -->
      Tags (Featherlight)
      <div id="tags-featherlight"></div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- Tags -->
  <br />
  Tags (No Featherlight)
  <div id="tags"></div>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/release/featherlight.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/taggle/1.11.2/taggle.js"></script>
  <script>
    new Taggle('tags');
    new Taggle('tags-featherlight');
  </script>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
@import 'https://sean.is/assets/styles/css/projects/taggle/taggle.min.css';

html, body { 
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
  background: white !important;
 }
.container { 
  display:none; 
 }
.form { 
  width:300px;
  height:200px;
  background:white;
  border:1px solid black; 
}
.taggle_input { 
  border: 1px solid gray !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because Featherlight/Taggle modifies your HTML.

This:

```
<form id="myform" class="form">
      <!-- Tags -->
      Tags (Featherlight)
      <div id="tags-featherlight"></div>
</form>
```

Becomes this:

```
<form id="myform" class="form featherlight-inner">
    <!-- Tags -->
    Tags (Featherlight)
    <div id="tags-featherlight"><span class="taggle_placeholder" style="opacity: 1;">Enter tags...</span>
      <ul class="taggle_list">
        <li>
          <input type="text" class="taggle_input" tabindex="-1" style="padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px;">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="taggle_sizer" style="font-size: 16px;"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Take note of the new CSS classes and ids, and then write your CSS rules accordingly.

Comment: I'm not seeing what to change. All of the classes and id's have remained the same for both Featherlight and Non-Featherlight Taggle input. The css is loaded from taggle.min.css.

Comment: Well what are you trying to style? The text inputs right?

Comment: The Taggle javascript styles the input automatically with taggle.min.css. But when in featherlight, it won't activate and apply.

Comment: According to your jsfiddle it is being applied - inspect the element and you will see it is

Comment: I'm not applying the css to the input tags manually. I applied an outline so you can see the box. The Taggle javascript applies css when you type a comma.

Comment: Ah sorry! I've found the problem now though - working on an answer

Comment: @MattMcManis I'm sorry but it seems the two don't play nice together - I would suggest trying other combinations

Comment: This is the full Taggle javascript. I wonder where it is trying to apply the css. https://github.com/okcoker/taggle.js/blob/master/src/taggle.js

Comment: I think you're right, I'm going to have to use another tag script.